# Add a "Magic 8-Ball" feature to the Ask a Question page

Tags: discussion, questions, search, fun

So many interesting questions get asked on Stack Overflow and then immediately closed (or worse yet, closed and re-opened for days on end) because they're subjective, argumentative, and fundamentally unanswerable due to our *lack of omniscience*: without the ability to see into the future and/or know the **secret motivations** of companies and their developers, we are left to make wildly varying (un)informed guesses.

The obvious solution to this is to add a [built-in clairvoyant](http://web.archive.org/web/20101231054449/http://av.vet.ksu.edu/flash/8ball/) feature to the Ask a Question page. Similar to the current "Related Questions" feature, this could be used to answer otherwise-unanswerable questions *before* they're asked, thus saving everyone time and frustration.

I propose a simple system whereby a web cam is aimed at an ordinary [Mattel Magic 8-Ball](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00001ZWV7) device, long recognized as one of the most accessible and accurate fortune-telling mechanisms available to modern society. A simple [vibrating pad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001EI7H3K) could be placed under this rig and triggered in response to the user's typing. Once focus leaves the `Title` input field, a short delay will be triggered, followed by a bit of logic to capture the 8-ball's result and feed it through a simple OCR routine to produce the result.

[image]

So far as I'm aware, SO would be the first major Q&A site to implement such a feature...

---

#### Examples:

- [Why was Google’s Chrome browser written almost entirely in C++ and not C# or Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623062/why-was-googles-chrome-browser-written-almost-entirely-in-c-and-not-c-or-java)
- [Why did Microsoft choose a RESTful API over WebDAV for BLOB storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/why-did-microsoft-choose-a-restful-api-over-webdav-for-blob-storage)
- [Why did Microsoft choose MVC for ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854807/why-did-microsoft-choose-mvc-for-asp-net)
- [Why did my wife divorce me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940654/why-did-my-wife-divorce-me)
- [Python brighter future than ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987722/python-brighter-future-than-ruby-closed)
- [Why isn’t OCaml more popular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433258/why-isnt-ocaml-more-popular)
- [Why is Github more popular than Gitorious?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78991/why-is-github-more-popular-than-gitorious)
- [Why isn’t Google Web Toolkit more popular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523728/why-isnt-google-web-toolkit-more-popular)

---

<sub>...another UV resurrection...</sub>

Comment: seems like a good idea for 4/1/2010

Comment: I'm speechless         .

Comment: Ok, is the "Why did my wife divorce me?" really a question? It returns not found for me. Upvote to the first answer with a screen shot of it.

Comment: @toast: http://www.shog9.com/whydivorce.png

Comment: @Shog9: That's hilarious, but I've already upvoted and favorited this question so my blatant selling of rep has failed.

Comment: *"Outlook not so good"* -- Yeah, I knew that already. That's why I use Thunderbird.

Comment: A _Magic 8_ ball won't help. Usually, the answer is _42_.

Comment: @Shog9 It seems the [built-in clairvoyant link](http://av.vet.ksu.edu/flash/8ball/) is broken. I get a 404 when I try to open it

Comment: if /why/ then return 'because.'

Comment: @Tijesunimi see now. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks!!! :)

Comment: related: [Rolling question rate limits are now network-wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/165773) "Additional just-in-time help (triggered while writing a question) is in the works..."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's not  a realistic feature request, it's a request that is basically ridiculing posts that are either opinion-based or are unanswerable on a Q&A platform.

Answer (score 42):

I got a magic 8-ball once from CDW with answers like "Try rebooting", "Reinstall", and "It's a bug".

Comment: Wow, swag that's actually useful *and* clever!

Comment: Oh, gettin' me one of *those*

Comment: lemme guess.  one of the other answers is *"it's a feature"*, right?

Answer (score 17):

How about a close option for "Magic 8-Ball Question", and then if it closed with that reason, the image appears (or even a random image from a set of images, in true Magic 8-Ball fashion)?

Answer (score 4):

To heck with the OCR, dudes, just give us the image!

And hey, I kind of liked that OCaml question :-)

Answer (score 2):

[SHA-0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm) (but not SHA-1) also has strong clairvoyant properties.  Simply hash the question, and count the number of alphabet (non-numeric) characters in the output.  If it is odd, the answer is yes.  If it is even, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You could code a simple program to post [here](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~ssanty/cgi-bin/eightball.cgi) and parse the html of the result to display it on SO... a simple GraseMonkey script could do it.

The page posts to itself passing the question in a field of name **query**