# How to raise close flag multiple times

Tags: discussion, flags

I raised a close flag for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920661/set-up-width-of-slide-out-menu-in-ios) question. I flagged it as **should be closed** -> **unclear what you're asking**. The downvotes show that there *is* actually *something* wrong with the question. Unfortunately the flag "aged away". As I pay close attention to the flags I am raising, I simply couldn't accept the fact that the flag has not been resolved and that question, which is very weak and has no answers is sitting there unanswered and "taking up space". So I raised another flag, because **should be closed** is not allowed anymore - I raised **very low quality**, hoping it would get resolved and instead I got *disputed*.

The downvote stat clearly shows it is not a good question. The fact that it doesn't have *ANY* answers is also a good indicator of it. How should this be handled if I can't raise the flag that aged away anymore?

**Fun fact:** The flag section now indicates that I have ALSO raised third option - **duplicate**. But that is not true, I only raised two flags (possible bug?).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33286/267587 It is important to remember that a downvote and a close vote are *not* the same, do not serve the same function, and that one does not indicate that the other should also be used.  Closed questions can be highly upvoted (Well-asked duplicates) and low-voted questions can be valid (appropriate question, poorly written).

Comment: related: [Don't let flag-to-close flags linger for months in flag purgatory](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250496/165773): "there's a hard limit of 14 days after the last vote or flag that they can remain active. Both votes and flags can now be [re-raised](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting) if they fall into this scenario..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can recast a close flag 14 days after it aged away, per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287321/4098326).

To answer your second question: marking as duplicate is technically a close reason, so it is by design.

Comment: Nice! I'll wait those 14 days and will get back with status update.

Comment: So the question got to score **-5** and I guess that the OP deleted it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

As a general principle, one user should not be able to raise multiple flags on a question.

If this were allowed, we would run the risk of people abusing it.  You have raised a flag, the rest of the community will either agree or disagree.

Yes, occasionally bad questions will survive but that isn't the end of the world.  The fact that it has downvotes does indicate that it is not considered to be a good question - let it be.

Comment: I see and agree to certain extent, but wouldn't it make sense only in case the flag was *declined*?

Comment: It is certainly true that a declined flag should not be re-raised but I don't think an expired flag should have any preferential treatment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are voting to close the question because it has been heavily downvoted, **you are closing it for the wrong reason**.  A low-score question is not necessarily a question that needs to be closed - it may simply be a very poorly-written question that is still valid for the site.  If you have a reason to believe it should be closed, flag it for that.

If you feel that your flags have not been received appropriately, or that the question should be closed for a reason that hasn't been addressed yet, you can always visit the meta page for the site, link the question, and start a topic asking if it should be closed - this is your last resort.

It is entirely possible that, despite this question being poorly-received, it is still valid and shouldn't be closed.  If you disagree, comment, flag, vote to close and Meta topics are your tools for making your voice heard. Looking at the question, my best guess is that it might be "too broad", but not knowing the language it refers to, I cannot make that call.