# since when is a question about the RTM of vs2010 not programming related?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

My question, [curious as to best guess of vs2010 RTM date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052815/curious-as-to-best-guess-of-vs2010-rtm-date) was:

> closed as **not programming related** by Greg D, John at CashCommons, Peter, OrbMan, Greg Hewgill 1 hour ago

Jeff Atwood, where are you?

Please explain to me how this question is ***not*** programming related?

As a .NET programmer in particular, and a programmer since 1967 in general, imnsho, the tools that I use and the availability of their **next generations** are very important (at least to me).

Also, a similar question, [When will C# 4.0 (and possibly 5.0) be released?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284397/when-will-c-4-0-and-possibly-5-0-be-released) is still open.

Comment: fwiw, I agree there's nothing wrong with the question. Sometimes it's just that time of the month for a random person on the net who has a better SO rep score than you. "ma always sed, laf slike abaxa chaklit"

Answer (score 6):

You weren't asking a programming question or a question about a tool used primarily for the purpose of programming. You were asking users to **guess** at the release schedule of a 3rd party. Right now, SO is not well equipped to provide answers to such questions; if you wish this to change, I recommend that you up-vote [this suggested change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page).

Comment: visual studio is a tool used almost exclusively for programming and for programming related matters.

seems to me that its text editor might also be used to write the great Canadian novel, but that would be an exceptional use.

I suspect that a few SO members may actually be able to answer that question.

Likewise, I also suspect that a good number really do care about release dates, even guestimates.

As for guessing, I managed to guess the release date of ASP.NET MVC v1.0 RTM so I suspect I'm not the only one in the crowd with apparently psychic knowledge.

regards ~~ gerry (lowry)

Comment: But the answer to your question has no intrinsic programming value.  Sure, programmers are likely to know things about the release schedule for programming related software... but they are also likely to know about lots of things that match the programmer demographic like Star Trek trivia, computer hardware, and user troubleshooting.  But just like your question, those things are only tangentially related.

Comment: If you imagine the year is now 2011 and said product has been released (hopefully), what value is this question and answer going to be when it appears in search results...it'll likely help no one and be of no value.

Comment: I suspect that a good number really do care about lottery numbers and winning horses. Doesn't mean they should be asking for advice on a finance or equine site.

Answer (score 3):

I explained why I voted to close in a comment:

> Unfortunately, questions that ask to predict the future aren't really appropriate here. Most of us don't know the answer; those of us who might know the answer aren't talking; and the information doesn't have lasting value anyway.

More information on this position can be found in the question [New close reason: “Question asks to predict the future”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20668/new-close-reason-question-asks-to-predict-the-future).

Comment: for me, there is value.  NOTE:  not every question needs to have lasting value; trivial example:  "Honey, what's for dinner?".  NOTE ALSO:  many questions are unlikely to have lasting value; example:  programming questions about "The Year 2000 Problem".

Answer (score 0):

You are asking **when a particular software product will be released**?

Now you tell me what *that* has to do with programming.

Comment: happy to oblidge you ...

take a look at "What's New in 2010", e.g.:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063%28VS.100%29.aspx.  Programming is NOT just about cranking out code.  Programming is also about planning approaches to current and future products.  Programming too is about preparing to train other programmers, to bring them up to speed.  Programming is about learning from past mistakes.  I'm guilty of wallowing too long in vs6 because I failed to realize the improvements of evolving versions.  So imo the question has great significance to programming in the .NET universe!!!

Comment: I'm still not convinced. You're just wondering if it will be released in Q1 or in Q2. This is really NOT programming related. What difference does it make for a *programmer* if the RTM gets released now or in three months? If you want to use it, you better download and install the preview *NOW*... Guessing when it will be out won't make you a better programmer. Heck not even a better manager for that matter.