# Help wanted: clean up the [future] tag

Tags: discussion, clean-up

I just found the [future](/questions/tagged/future) tag on Stack Overflow.

Most questions there ([now 109 non-closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfuture%5D%20closed:0)) ask about events that will or will not happen in the future (relative to the time the question was asked or is read).

Most of these are either off-topic (not about programming), not constructive ("What do you think will happen?") or not a real question.

There are some legitimate questions here, about the [future construct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) in concurrent programming, or about the `from __future__ import ...` feature in Python (though maybe those should get different tags).

**So, if you can vote to close, help us looking at those questions and close the ones which are not suitable for Stack Overflow.** Please do not vote to migrate to Programmers Stack Exchange, as they don't want prophesy questions, either.

Some of these questions might also be saved by a good edit. Though have a look at existing answers first.

It  might also help to write a good tag wiki to avoid new questions about the future.

Comment: I'll admit it's  a pretty vague badge, but judging by top-voted questions, it is popular - http://i.imgur.com/Gtn0F.png

Comment: You can see that most those high-voted questions are quite old (from 2008 or 2009). They would be closed almost immediately if asked now - the sense of the community what is on-topic has changed since then.

Comment: @Adel: Badge? Don't you mean tag? @ Paulo: I'd like to help if someone also helps me with this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109074/get-rid-of-suggestions-advice-recommendation-and-likes Seeing no one person helping is really demotivating.

Comment: Related: [Are strongly on-topic questions about predicting the future allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56480/are-strongly-on-topic-questions-about-predicting-the-future-allowed)

Comment: Well, [not all questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017391/how-to-control-orders-in-which-java-futures-are-submitted) [tagged {future}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713262/how-to-deal-with-exceptions-in-scala-futures) [are improperly tagged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80447/what-are-futures), but in these cases, it's just for lack of the proper tag(s).

Comment: @Nightfirecat: Yes, those question are tagged right (I think), the problem are the ones. (Which makes it a bit difficult to measure the progress here.)

Comment: I feel like adding the [futures] tag would be helpful in this case, as futures seem to be a legitimate programming topic, where future seems to refer more generally to the word's definition (which we're trying to discourage).

Comment: Maybe we should ask Chris/Anna/Mark if they want some of those over at Programmers.

Comment: I'm also tempted to change the title to `Captain Paŭlo And The World Of The Future Tag`...

Comment: @Bobby: As I already said above, these questions are off-topic on Programmers, if they are about prognosing the future. (And sorry, I don't really get your joke in the alternative title ... I found [Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_Captain_and_the_World_of_Tomorrow), but I don't see how it relates.)

Comment: From only reading the titles I'd say some *might* fit over there. Of course not with that tag. And yes, that's what jumped into my mind for no special reason.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to start going through and removing the [future](/questions/tagged/future) tag off some open questions that don't need it, and voting to close those that are speculative. One other tag that may need looking at is [future-development](/questions/tagged/future-development).

Comment: Ah, you swamped my [tag filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/19305/small-tags-sites)! Thanks for your activity (specially the close-votes).

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, the [future-proof](/questions/tagged/future-proof) tag probably ought be checked through - not all of them are badly tagged, but a good number are related.