# Google Sidewiki impact

Tags: discussion, google

Will the impact of [sidewiki](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/09/help-and-learn-from-others-as-you.html) on SO be positive, negative, or zero?

Answer (score 5):

**I refuse to risk my everlasting soul by practicing divination for such a banal purpose.**

If you're *really* interested in finding an answer here, I suggest you [vote for this enhancement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page).

---

Seriously though? This idea has been [tried before](http://www.wikalong.org/) ([several times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_annotation), actually) - unless it develops a large and dedicated following, i highly doubt it'll have any impact on anything, at all.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it can be used in several ways:

[image]

Comment: AAAAAAHHHHHHHHH!!

Comment: +1 he sounds neat. His Wiki states he's known for, ["being l33t as all hell"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:EvanCarroll). I think he should come back.