# Can we have a "mind-reading" badge

Tags: discussion, fun, badge-request

> *Accepted answer for a question which provided  few details.*

If we do, I think I earn it! :)

[java “cannot find symbol” - how to import a file in the same directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799983/java-cannot-find-symbol-how-to-import-a-file-in-the-same-directory/1800073#1800073)

Answer (score 9):

**Sure**, here you go:

[Uri Geller http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7186/urigeller.png](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7186/urigeller.png)

Comment: Dude, it's not even in *order*...

Comment: Uri Geller needs no order, he bends spoons, warps time and reads minds

Comment: brilliant! :)))

Comment: The image dead, without it this answer is weird (probably so was the image)

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it'll happen.

I'll take my future-seeing badge now.

Answer (score 3):

Go ahead and add it to the master badge request list:

[Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas)

Answer (score 2):

**Sure**, but I think it will happen after: [Add a “Magic 8-Ball” feature to the Ask a Question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page), I think it is a pre-requisite for your magical feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the "OMG-Lucky!" badge, or "Fixed 100 syntax errors" badge.

Comment: I hope you do not mind me tagging this as always-friday-in-iceland, someone tells me it is always Friday there, and it explains many

Comment: thank-god-its-iceland

Comment: Why is it I keep getting the "OMG-not-Lucky!" for inheriting projects that have 100 syntax errors... (I consider PHP warnings to be equivalent.)

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what Oscar might mean. I ran into [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854277/how-to-get-value-from-match-in-actionscript/1857004#1857004):

> How to get value from match in
>   actionscript? Has Anyone show me an
>   example?

It's such a minor thing, but:
from a 'technical' point of view, clearly "OMG-Lucky" badge for me.
The truth behind it is that a couple of weeks before I personally ran into
a "get value from match" situation.

When I spotted that, it clicked and
I felt that the person asking experienced the same frustration(being so close, but not quite there) I went through with the same issue.

'Technically', sure, 'lucky' is the correct term, but I don't believe there is any technical way of measuring intuition, or how people that don't know each other anonymously 'connect' based similar frequencies/intensities of emotions/wavelengths.

Call me a hippie, but this stuff exists.

There will never be a badge for that though :)
Not only it not something to measure, but because for a stackoverflow badge would be meaninngless compared to the confirmation that one's emotion driven intuition won over one's analytical thinking.