# Does Stack Overflow have automated tests?

Tags: discussion, testing

Does Stack Overflow have automated tests? If yes, what kind of (unit, integration, etc)? How are they organized and used?

Comment: While it's true that this question is about Stack Overflow, it's more of a programming-related question using a specific project as an example. You could replace "Stack Overflow" with "phpBB" and the question would still be valid. However, it's not really a suitable question for meta.

Comment: The problem is that it is Stack Overflow related. It would get closed on Stack Overflow because "It's about Stack Overflow". It belongs here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jeff has previously stated that certain aspects of the site's code have unit tests, but not very many. He and Joel aren't unit testing's biggest advocates ;)

Comment: You sir win the "understatement of the year" award for the last part.

Comment: When I heard Jeff say on a podcast that they had some unit tests - that made me chuckle. 'Some' are ok as long as they test the parts of the code you care about - i.e. the ones with most 'business value' - but from the podcasts I doubt the team hold much value in unit testing - or maintaining the unit tests they have ... although I could, as ever, be very wrong!

Comment: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/6982898125

Answer (score 6):

Due to extensive use of [IoC containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code/871420#871420) the code base for Stackoverflow is extremely testable, the bulk of the tests are written in [Cobol](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001294.html) and [Brainf*ck](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/brainfuck/index.php), a smaller yet significant portion is tested using 42 [magic 8 balls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page), which when shaken in harmony produce magnificent and hypnotizing sounds.

Answer (score 4):

This goes without saying, but IMHO.

Individual **reusable components** are eminently testable. So much so that they are *huge* wins, and you'd be a fool not to have tons of unit testing wrapped around them.

Thinks like.. say... our [c# markdown processor](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/).

However, **almost none of the code that most programmers produce on real world, typical projects is actually reusable in any meaningful way**. And writing truly reusable code is about two orders of magnitude harder -- even with unit tests -- than writing typical one-off "just get it done" code. It takes many times the amount of effort to produce the same result if you want to build something that is legitimately reusable.

Related: The "Rule of Three"
http://maheshpai.info/?p=20

Comment: WTF has unit testing to do with reusable components? Who says that only reusable components are unit-testable? I do not think that everything has to be unit-tested to death, but this argument is pure nonsense. Or maybe I'm missing something here.