# Radical Idea: A "Wish I Knew" button

Tags: feature-request

It's all in the title, somewhat self explanatory. A couple points though, it would...

1. be helpful with various
   StackOverflow algorithms
2. create unique opportunity
   'subscription' capability whereas
   when *it is thought (algorithm?)* an
   answer has been 'found' then the
   user is somehow informed/notified
   an answer has been found.

Comment: So, comments and question feeds?

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Not really that self-explanatory but it's a quarter til 3 in the a.m. so I might be a little dense right now.

Comment: I suppose less cumbersome for the end-user.

Comment: -1 No it's not self-explanatory.  I do not understand this question at all.

Comment: this already exists; look for the button labelled **"Ask Question"**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what the question author is talking about, but...

Sometimes you stumble on interesting questions that are still not answered or don't have many answers, and you would like to check it back later. Right now you can either favorite this question or subscribe to the question feed at the bottom of the page. The question feed is very good, but it would be nicer of that was a feature of SO itself. Marking the question as a favorite isn't a bad option, you can sort your favorites by recent activities and check them manually.

An integrated page for answers and comments feed might make it easier to keep track of such question and maintain the distinction between a favorite question (which is closer to a browser bookmark) and this feature (closer to question feed). Or perhaps both features could be somehow combined. Some people use browser bookmarks for pages that aren't really bookmark-worthy, but which they'd like to visit later, so I'm not sure if the distinction is really worth it.

To sum it up I'm interested in something like that but not sure if it's really worth it. I wanted to write a post in support of this idea, but the more I think about it it seems that it might lead to confusion and duplicated effort.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this already exist? Tempted to close as duplicate of..

[Add a "Magic 8-Ball" feature to the Ask a Question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page)