# Related Questions should search across all related SOI sites

Tags: feature-request, related-questions, duplicate-questions

When *Ask*ing *a Question*, the suggested dupes shown in *Related Questions* should come from across all *related* SOI sites.

This would help users figure out if they are asking a question on the wrong site.  It would also help prevent the duplicate-asking of questions which might be found on both sites.

This is especially important for *SuperUser* and *ServerFault*, where the distinction is not clear to new users and where many questions overlap and preemptive elimination of redundancy would be quite helpful.

Eventually, tags could even be used to discover what is related.  Tagging a question *Linux* or *Ubuntu* or *Debian* could cause searching of, or increase the chance of results appearing from, the Unix/Linux and Ubuntu SE sites, for instance.

Comment: Imagine asking a question on SO about Java and getting loads of questions from coffee.stackexchange.com...

Comment: Changed to indicate *all related* sites instead of *ALL* sites.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually the "where should I ask this question" function (codename: [magic 8 ball](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page)) will be assumed by http://stackexchange.com

But as stated, we have no intention of implementing.

Comment: @AStu: I kinda like that idea. Targeted advertising for other SE sites. Just think of all the CookingSE links we could get on Meta...

Comment: @Shog9 Of course the corpse-eating question on gaming.se would always have a spot in the "related" section on cooking.se

Comment: @Shog9 @balpha As indicated, I suggested offering *Related Question* suggestions across all *related* SOI sites, for example *SuperUser* between and *ServerFault*.

Comment: What do you have "no intention of implementing", the *magic 8 ball*, or the displaying of Related Questions from SuperUser on ServerFault (in an appropriately-marked subsection) and visa-versa?

Comment: @AStu: If you plan to use tags for determining relationships, you might find some [interesting](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waffle) [relations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waffles) appearing...