# Where can I ask general question about quality of some product?

Tags: discussion

See the question [java/Jdk 7 release schedule for mission-critical production use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419219/java-jdk-7-release-schedule-for-mission-critical-production-use). While this question likely does not belong in so, I am wondering which is the right se forum to ask.

It is impossible today to find a better audience to answer this question then se. But which site?

Comment: I think it's too speculative (as phrased) for anywhere on the network.

Comment: And who better to speculate then the experts here. I do mean this seriously.

Comment: Speculation leads to subjective discussions and argument, which is specifically discouraged on the SE network.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nowhere.  It is entirely too subjective, and is too localized in time.  Remember, just because a question can be asked doesn't mean it has a home on SE.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, your question is very similar to one [already asked here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98441/how-safe-it-is-to-do-minor-jvm-upgrades).

Crucial difference? That question - and the answers - focus on what *you* can do to avoid unexpected problems in a new JDK release. Speculation as to the quality and release schedule of future updates is kept to a minimum.

I rather suspect that's what you're looking for anyway. But if not, please note that the SE system is *currently* ill-equipped to answer such questions. However, [I've proposed a change that would allow them to be served here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page) - vote it up...